# Create Cron Job in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, cron-task

I've created the command with the help of following link,
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html

I want to create a crone job that will run the command I've created every day.

I'm working on MAC Mountain Lion .

How to achieve this ?

Thanks,

Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 1):

If you have symfony2 console command you should add something like

```
0 0 * * *   cd /var/www/path_to_your_symfony2_project && ./app/console your_symfony2_command --env=prod
```

Comment: I think it should be `... php ./app/console ...`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running a unix host, you can just create the cronjob by running `crontab -e` and pointing to the PHP file.

If you can run the command in the format `php dosomething.php` you can create a cron task.

To run a task every day at 0:00 you write the following in your crontab after running `crontab -e` at your terminal:

> 0 0 * * * /home/you/public_html/yourscript.php

Comment: By opening a shell and typing crontab -e, OSX comes with crontab installed.